# Iteration of json array to display in a flask API - single entry displayed?

Tags: json, python-3.x, api, for-loop, flask

I'd appreciate some help with the following python problem. I have a json that looks like this:

```
  "gene": {
    "entrezGeneId": 7157,
    "entrezGeneSymbol": "TP53"
  },
  "termAssoc": [
    {
      "ontologyId": "HP:0100592",
      "name": "Peritoneal abscess",
      "definition": "The presence of an abscess of the peritoneum."
    },
    {
      "ontologyId": "HP:0002756",
      "name": "Pathologic fracture",
      "definition": "A pathologic fracture occurs when a bone breaks in an area that is weakened secondarily to another disease process such as tumor, infection, and certain inherited bone disorders. A pathologic fracture can occur without a degree of trauma required to cause fracture in healthy bone."
    },
    {
      "ontologyId": "HP:0005513",
      "name": "Increased megakaryocyte count",
      "definition": "Increased megakaryocyte number, i.e., of platelet precursor cells, present in the bone marrow."
    },
    {
      "ontologyId": "HP:0004396",
      "name": "Poor appetite",
      "definition": ""
    },
```

I am building a simple Flask API where an input is submitted and specific entries are extracted I want to extract the ontologyId from the array. I tried iterating:

```
class HPO_Class(Resource):
    def get(self, Entrez_ID):
        result=url_func(Entrez_ID)
        for ID in result['termAssoc']:
            data= ID['ontologyId']
        return data
```

But that returns only one entry

[API response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVIu2.png)

I understand that this is a json array and I am missing something but I am stumped. I tried the following

```
class HPO_Class(Resource):
    def get(self, Entrez_ID):
        result=url_func(Entrez_ID)
        for ID in result['termAssoc']:
            data= ID
        return data
```

But that returns

```
{
  "ontologyId": "HP:0003010",
  "name": "Prolonged bleeding time",
  "definition": "Prolongation of the time taken for a standardized skin cut of fixed depth and length to stop bleeding."
}
```

Only a single entry appears. I have no idea what to do and am hoping for some insight into my lacking of understanding of this problem :) Thank you

BTW url_func is just a function to create and get requests for the API. Code is below if it helps:

```
import requests, sys, json
from pprint import pprint
import re

#Function to create url for HPO API, gene_id = Entrez ID
def url_func(gene_id):
    base_url = 'https://hpo.jax.org/api/hpo/gene'

    ext = gene_id

    url= '/'.join([base_url, ext]) # url is join at the / amd consists of base url and ext

    #GET requests using get function from requests, url is the argument
    r = requests.get(url, headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"})

    #requests check, if not valid the fcuntion will exit from python
    if not r.ok:
        r.raise_for_status()
        sys.exit()

    return(r.json()) #returns results as json
```

Thank you for all your help!! :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone keeping track. I found the answer in the end. Here is how I wrote this function in the end

```
def get(self, Entrez_ID):
        result=url_func(Entrez_ID, mode = 1, no_results=-1)
        data=[]
        for ID in result['termAssoc']:
            data.append(ID.get('ontologyId'))
            #data= (ID.get('ontologyId'))
        return data
```

That solved it and it return a dictionary of the entries  need

```
[
  "HP:0000822",
  "HP:0002894",
  "HP:0006491",
  "HP:0045040",
  "HP:0100787",
  "HP:0002910",
  "HP:0030392",
  "HP:0002254",
  "HP:0002861",
  "HP:0004808",
  "HP:0002863",
  "HP:0200063",
  "HP:0030448",
  "HP:0100526",
  "HP:0100576",
  "HP:0001433",
  "HP:0002756",
  "HP:0100592",
  "HP:0006744",
  "HP:0004389",
  "HP:0000952",
  "HP:0009919",
  "HP:0002891",
  "HP:0002013",
  "HP:0003010",
  "HP:0012639",
  "HP:0002797",
  "HP:0002027",
  "HP:0100743",
  "HP:0004322",
  "HP:0006572",
  "HP:0003003",
  "HP:0000739",
  "HP:0100768",
  "HP:0001738",
  "HP:0004374",
  "HP:0030406",
  "HP:0005584",
  "HP:0001065",
  "HP:0001962",
  "HP:0025269",
  "HP:0100659",
  "HP:0002488",
  "HP:0000975",
  "HP:0011875",
  "HP:0002859",
  "HP:0003002",
  "HP:0003118",
  "HP:0200022",
  "HP:0002890",
  "HP:0100605",
  "HP:0001824",
  "HP:0000238",
  "HP:0002039",
  "HP:0004324",
  "HP:0001263",
  "HP:0006753",
  "HP:0001428",
  "HP:0001909",
  "HP:0006489",
  "HP:0000819",
  "HP:0011027",
  "HP:0004936",
  "HP:0002750",
  "HP:0012125",
  "HP:0006725",
  "HP:0011974",
  "HP:0012410",
  "HP:0000135",
  "HP:0012030",
  "HP:0001413",
  "HP:0005561",
  "HP:0025435",
  "HP:0100006",
  "HP:0000252",
  "HP:0100543",
  "HP:0001945",
  "HP:0003401",
  "HP:0012288",
  "HP:0002017",
  "HP:0000029",
  "HP:0000737",
  "HP:0012539",
  "HP:0001402",
  "HP:0002669",
  "HP:0000006",
  "HP:0001276",
  "HP:0002018",
  "HP:0003155",
  "HP:0410067",
  "HP:0001250",
  "HP:0001658",
  "HP:0005249",
  "HP:0002667",
  "HP:0001872",
  "HP:0025380",
  "HP:0500022",
  "HP:0009726",
  "HP:0002315",
  "HP:0004420",
  "HP:0005513",
  "HP:0003110",
  "HP:0004313",
  "HP:0002888",
  "HP:0012126",
  "HP:0000080",
  "HP:0001085",
  "HP:0000505",
  "HP:0012334",
  "HP:0010982",
  "HP:0030078",
  "HP:0001425",
  "HP:0001744",
  "HP:0002665",
  "HP:0030348",
  "HP:0002664",
  "HP:0000859",
  "HP:0003466",
  "HP:0004396",
  "HP:0012531",
  "HP:0006716",
  "HP:0000944",
  "HP:0003418",
  "HP:0001903",
  "HP:0012174",
  "HP:0012189",
  "HP:0025134",
  "HP:0001386",
  "HP:0025436",
  "HP:0002326",
  "HP:0002900",
  "HP:0100630",
  "HP:0001939",
  "HP:0011748",
  "HP:0010788",
  "HP:0007378",
  "HP:0100749",
  "HP:0002896",
  "HP:0001324",
  "HP:0002716",
  "HP:0006740",
  "HP:0006721",
  "HP:0009592",
  "HP:0012740",
  "HP:0012432",
  "HP:0025318",
  "HP:0100615",
  "HP:0002885",
  "HP:0000998",
  "HP:0030070"
]
```

Cheers